# Healing skills scale with magicka?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In The Elder Scrolls Online, do healing skills scale with magicka ?

Comment: Are you asking whether Magicka scales with Healing Skills, or vice-versa?

Comment: The more you have magicka the more you heal ? That's my point :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been explained in [one issue](http://elderscrollsonline.com/en-uk/news/post/2013/12/09/ask-us-anything-progression) of their *Ask us Anything* series.

> **Do attributes (health, magicka, and stamina) affect more than just HP and your magicka or stamina pool (like resistances, speed, etc.)?**
>
> Yes. Your attributes will affect certain other stats. Some of these will be exposed, but others will be more behind the scenes. As an example, magicka affects not just how many spells you can cast, but their overall efficacy as well.

**Quick rule of thumb:**

- If your skill consumes **magicka**, then **magicka** will increase its number values.
- If your skill consumes **stamina**, then **stamina** will increase its number values.

Also note that - as this [kb article explains](https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5206/) - most weapon abilities will consume **stamina**, staffs being the exception as they consume **magicka**.

> **Do bows require stamina to shoot? And do Restoration or Destruction staves cost Magicka to use? Or is there some other resource used for staves?**
>
> Normal attacks with weapons don't require stamina or magicka. If players learn abilities for that weapon, these abilities will have a cost associated with them. Almost all weapon abilities, including those for the bow, will consume stamina. Staves are the exception—their abilities consume magicka.

Comment: Very good an clear answer !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the amount your spells heal is determined by your magicka. High magicka means more powerful healing spells.

Comment: Do you have any sources ? Or others can confirm it ?

Comment: There's a decent video on youtube that shows how magicka and stamina contribute to skill damage here: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr_OIx7bp7g).